How to remove "Current read only: yes" attribute in USB flash drive
This is USB recovery flash drive given to me when I bought my laptop I want to install other Operating system in that flash drive but when I try to format it it says "USB is write protected" in windows 10

There are such things as readonly thumb drives - e.g. my Windows 10 drive from Microsoft is readonly and there is no way to change that - thumb drives are cheap, buy one

This may also happen in the wild as an error, but you can fix it.
Remind that the Device may have been Hardlocked, which cant be fixed.

List item

Open Command Prompt as Administrator.

cmd


in the "black box", you start

diskpart


While you are into the Disk part environment., Run the command

list disk



This command will list all the storage drives currently connected and recognized in your system.

If you are sure, that you found the correct one,

select disk <index_number>
Use the index number associated to the drive. For example, select "disk 2".
if you are unsure, you can double-check by Volume

list volume





Run the command the following to clear the read-only status

attributes disk clear read only

If you select the Volume, the Disk will be selected automatically. You can also cheat with diskmgmt.msc for Visual double check, but it's not the recommended way ;).
